# Vuetify.js Data Table Initially Unsorted

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there any way to specify the initial sort on a Veutify.js Data Table?

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables

I would like the initial state to be unsorted, but by default it's setting the first column as the sort column.

Comment: doesn't this work? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#example-sort

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it:

```
disable-initial-sort
```